# Oracle Forms Global Exit in JNLP

Tags: oracle, jnlp, oracleforms

I've the following problem:

I have an Oracle forms Application where the User can call multiple Forms.
I also have an Menu with an Logout button, that should close all open Forms.

When this button is pressed I set :GLOBAL.LOGOFF to 'TRUE'. And in WHEN_WINDOW_ACTIVATED I have placed the following code.

```
DEFAULT_VALUE('FALSE','GLOBAL.LOGOFF');
IF (:GLOBAL.LOGOFF = 'TRUE') THEN
    COMMIT;
    DO_KEY('EXIT_FORM');
END IF;
```

This whole thing also works when the Oracle Forms Application is called from a browser.
But when I call it via JNLP it crashes the application. I get the following errors:

```
FRM-40735: WHEN-FORM-NAVIGATE
FRM-40735: WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE
FRM-40735: WHEN-WINDOW-DEACTIVATED
```

All with:

```
ORA-06508
```

I don't understand how the Forms Application is reacting differently depending on if it is executed via JNLP or from a Browser.

Comment: These triggers raised *unhandled exceptions*, but - which ones? There must be something else in the error stack (I'd expect some ORA-xxxxx error). Do you see any?

Comment: It is an: ORA-06508

Comment: That's "could not find program unit being called". So, which program units do you call, and they aren't available to user currently connected?

Comment: All should be available, its plls that are assigned to the fmb.
Everything works fine, without errors, when i call the application via the browser. It only doesn't work when I call it via JNLP.

Comment: No further ideas, sorry; did you try to search MOS or raise a service request? Maybe it is a bug. Or, if it is not, someone else might be able to assist. Good luck!

Comment: I just verified it, I deleted the calls to the PLLS and it works without crashing now. But the problem still persists that it works with plls when called from browser but it crashes with JNLP.

Answer (score 0):

Although I question why you are doing logoff handling in a `WHEN_WINDOW_ACTIVATED` trigger, it is possible what you are seeing is related to a known issue.  Refer to these Oracle bugs that all map together.  You may need to work with Oracle Support as some of the bugs and/or their content may not be visible to you.  `9764631, 22724515, 26996652`

Also, if you are not already using **12.2.1.3**, you will need to update your version in order to get the fix I mentioned.

Helpful resource:
https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/forms